# How to configure Gnome to use the icon from the .desktop file in the Dock?

Tags: gnome, .desktop, 17.10, dock

I have a `.desktop` launcher in `~/.local/share/applications`. I have specified an `Icon` there. This icon is visible in the "Activities launcher". But when i select it, the icon is not used in the Dock.

With Unity, the icon from the `.desktop` file was used.

**How to configure Gnome to use the icon from the `.desktop` file in the Dock?**

Answer (score 0):

GNOME uses the application launchers found in the `~/.local/share/applications` directory. If you move your application launcher there, it should change the icon in both the applications dashboard and the dock. Desktop launcher files placed here will override desktop launchers in `/usr/share/applications` by the same file name for your user only.

As an example, I changed the icon for Google Chrome to the 2048 logo. It appears in both the application dashboard and dock:

[image: dock] -- [image: dashboard]

Contents of `~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Google Chrome
Comment=Access the Internet
Icon=2048
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
```

Comment: Does not work for me. I suppose this is because my launcher points to a script which starts an application which has no icon.

Comment: Could you post the full contents of your `.desktop` file in your original question? If I can see how you're launching the script, it might help.